# Why won't my Handlebar lib load? - Requirejs

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, handlebars.js

I am trying to use the `requirejs-hbs` lib in a Backbone project.  I have the `Handlebars` lib and the `requirejs-hbs` lib in the same folder.  They are declared the same in my `config`.  When I look at the sources in my chrome tab, I am only getting the `require-hbs` script, I am not getting the `handlebars` script.  Here is my config file:

```
require.config({
  hbs: {
    templateExtension: '.hbs'
  },
  paths: {
    backbone: "libs/backbone/backbone",
    Handlebars: 'libs/handlebars/handlebars.amd',
    hbs: 'libs/requirejs-hbs/hbs',
    jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery',
    underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore'
  },
  shim: {
    backbone: {
      deps: [
        'underscore',
        'jquery'
      ],
      exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    underscore: {
      exports: '_'
    }
  }
});

require(['js/router/easier.view'], function(View) {
  'use strict';

  var view = new View();
});
```

And here is the view where I am trying to access my template.

```
define(function(require) {
  'use strict';

  var Backbone = require('backbone');
  var testTemplate = require('hbs!views/test.hbs');

  var router = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
      debugger;
    }
  });

  return router;
});
```

The error I get is `GET http://localhost:9000/handlebars.js 404 (Not Found)`.  I have the other files that I am declaring, but I do not have the `handlebars.js`.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a path to `Handlebars` but if you look at the source of **requirejs-hbs** you see that it uses `handlebars`.

So either change the **requirejs-hbs** source to `Handlebars` or change your path to `handlebars`.

Should work.